# Send data to Azure Event Hub using HTTP Post iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, azure, authorization, azure-eventhub

I have been trying to post data to Azure Event Hub using HTTP post in my iOS application but I am getting "**401 40103: Invalid authorization token signature**" error. I have followed the exact same steps mentioned [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-shared-access-signature-authentication/) to generate a Shared Access Signature token. Here is my code to generate token

```
- (NSString *)createTokenFromResourceUri:(NSString *)resourceUri keyName:(NSString *)keyName key:(NSString *)key {
    NSInteger expiry = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    expiry = expiry + 3600;      //Adding 1 hour

    NSString *encodedUrl = [resourceUri stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *stringToSign = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%ld", encodedUrl, (long)expiry];

    const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [stringToSign cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

    NSData *HMAC = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    NSString *hash = [HMAC base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SharedAccessSignature sig=%@&se=%ld&skn=%@&sr=%@", hash, (long)expiry, keyName, encodedUrl];
}
```

and then I post data using http client

```
self.httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:uri]];
[self.httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:[self createTokenFromResourceUri:uri keyName:keyName key:key]];
[self.httpClient postPath:nil parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation operation, NSError error) {
}];
```

I am also writing an Android client and getting the same error there as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Accroding to the [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652140.aspx), the first item of `stringToSign` is `baseAddress`, not `resourceURi`. Please try again.

Comment: Tried with the base address, still getting the same error.